# Oauth card doesn't return token when sign-in invoke activity is triggered from mobile device

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have implemented an OAuth sign in flow for my teams bot using Microsoft AAD v2 and the OAuthPrompt dialog with the help of [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample).

My dialog definition is as followed:

```
AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
            nameof(OAuthPrompt),
            new OAuthPromptSettings
            {
                ConnectionName = configuration["ConnectionName"],
                Text = "Please Sign In",
                Title = "Sign In",
                Timeout = 300000,
                EndOnInvalidMessage = true
            }));
```

and I initiate it as the first step of my root dialog

```
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginPromptAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
}
```

I'm also passing the invoke activity using the `OnTeamsSigninVerifyStateAsync` function

```
protected override async Task OnTeamsSigninVerifyStateAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
}
```

It is working fine on the desktop client, but while trying to sign in from my mobile device, the bot receives the response without the token.

The authentication flow is almost similar to the one implemented in [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-teams-authentication/csharp)

I tried adding 'login.microsoftonline.com' as well as 'token.botframework.com' to `validDomains` property in the manifest to no avail.
I also added
`devicePermissions": [ "openExternal" ]`
to the manifest, again to no avail.

I also tried debugging the bot locally and found that the sign in invoke activity from a mobile device results in the following [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRkvm.png)

**UPDATE**: I found that the [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-teams-authentication/csharp) (from which I picked up the authentication flow) also fails to login through mobile, I'm unable to figure out whether the problem is something from my side or from the sample code being outdated.

It'd be super helpful if somebody could clone the sample and see if results are the same.

Comment: Is there any console error you are getting? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/developer-tools#access-devtools-from-an-android-device

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I've updated my question to show an image of the 404 error response

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I used ngrok to debug the bot, couldn't debug the bot using usb debugging as Teams app was not getting picked up in the DevTools page

Comment: @Anthony Mathew - We also tried the mentioned [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-teams-authentication/csharp) and observed that it fails to login through mobile. The sign in invoke activity from a mobile device result in 404 error. We have raised a bug for this issue and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT - Hey, do you have any further updates on this issue?

Comment: Currently there is no update to share. Engineering team is investigating the issue. We will inform you once we get any update from them. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies. Currently there is no ETA to share. We are following up with engineering team about this issue. We will update this thread once we hear from them. Thanks!